# Removing Implicit Trendline In Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, interpolation, normalization

I have 2 [T,1] vectors of the position and velocity of a rat running back and forth on a linear track over several trials.

My goal is to 'normalize' the velocity such that at each time t, the new velocity vector will not reflect the absolute velocity, but the 'relative velocity', defined as the difference between the rat's actual speed at that position and its median (or mean) speed at that position.

Here is my current code, but I feel its very inefficient due to (1) numerical complexity (2) inability to 'smooth' the median across position (3) need to define a 'grid' whose resolution is inversely proportional to speed:

```
%% NOTE, pos=position ranges from 0 to 420 & dir=direction & is either 1/-1
med_speed=speed;
grid=linspace(0,max(pos),200);   %make grid of arbitrary spacing
[~,I]=histc(pos,grid);   
tic
for i=1:length(grid)
    I1=I==i & dir==1; I2=I==i & dir==-1;
    med_speed(I1)=median(med_speed(I1)); 
    med_speed(I2)=median(med_speed(I2));
end
toc  
norm_speed=speed-med_speed;

%%Plot
subplot(121), plot(pos,speed);
hold on, plot(pos,med_speed,'r','LineWidth',2), hold off
legend('Velocity','Median Velocity at that Position');
xlabel('Position'); ylabel('Speed'); axis tight
subplot(122), plot(pos,norm_speed)
xlabel('Position'); ylabel('Normalized Speed')
```

The obtained figure is below.

[image]

I feel like there is a way to do this with interp1....

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thnx!

Answer (score 0):

You can use medfilt1, e.g.

```
med_speed=medfilt1(speed,10);
```

will compute the median over 10 consecutive samples, going through the whole time series.

Not sure how you deal with scale in your normalization, i.e. typically you would take the difference between e.g. the median (or mean) over some period and divide by the standard deviation to account for the possibility of different scales in your data. Difference between running mean and actual value might work for one rat, but not if you want to compare n rats, each of which could perform at a different base speed.